# How to suppress the warming message by R when using commandArgs()

Tags: r, arguments

Here is my code:

```
Args <- commandArgs();
for(i in 1:length(Args)){
    if(Args[i] == "--input")      input  = Args[i+1]
    if(Args[i] == "--output")     fig = Args[i+1]
    if (Args[i] == "--height")    fig_height = as.numeric(Args[i+1])
    if (Args[i] == "--width")     fig_width  = as.numeric(Args[i+1])
}
cat(input, fig, fig_height, fig_width, "\n")
```

I put it in a text file. If I run this code on the terminal:

`R --vanilla --slave --input xx --height 10 --width 14 --output out < test.R`

I'll get the warning message shown as below:

WARNING: unknown option '--input'

ARGUMENT 'xx' **ignored**

WARNING: unknown option '--height'

ARGUMENT '10' **ignored**

WARNING: unknown option '--width'

ARGUMENT '14' **ignored**

WARNING: unknown option '--output'

ARGUMENT 'out' **ignored**

xx out 10 14

**How can I get rid of** the `WARNING` and 'ARGUMENT 'xx' __ignored__'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to avoid warning message:
Instead of using:

```
R --vanilla --slave --input xx --height 10 --width 14 --output out < test.R
```

I use:

```
Rscript test.R --input xx --height 10 --width 14 --output out
```

Then there is no warning message and here is the output:

```
xx out 10 14
```

Hope this can help others.